# What is the time complexity of this LC problem

Tags: time-complexity

Can anyone walk me through the analysis of the time complexity for this problem?
https://leetcode.com/problems/palindrome-partitioning/

I had a solution using DFS + backtracking + DP as below, I guess in terms of time complexity, it boils down to the number of partitions you could have for the worts case, but was struggling to figure out what it is.

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<string> cur;
    vector<vector<string>> ans;
    vector<vector<bool>> isPalindrome;
    unordered_map<int,vector<int>> pairs;

    vector<vector<string>> partition(string s) {
        isPalindrome.resize(s.length(),vector<bool>(s.length(),false));
        buildPalindromePairs(s);
        backtracking(s,0);
        return ans;
    }

    void buildPalindromePairs(string s)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<s.length();++i)
        {
            for(int j=i;j>=0;j--)
            {
                if(i==j) 
                    isPalindrome[j][i]=true;
                else if(j==i-1 && s[j]==s[i]) 
                    isPalindrome[j][i]=true;
                else if(s[j]==s[i] && isPalindrome[j+1][i-1])
                    isPalindrome[j][i]=true;

                if(isPalindrome[j][i])
                    pairs[j].push_back(i);
            }
        }
    }

    void backtracking(string s, int start)
    {
        if(start==s.length()) 
        {
            ans.push_back(cur);
            return;
        }

        for(auto end:pairs[start])
        {
            cur.push_back(s.substr(start, end-start+1));
            backtracking(s,end+1);
            cur.pop_back();
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `isPalindrome()` can be solved in `O(n)`.

The method `buildPalindromePairs(string s)` is `O(n^2)` as there in a nested for loop.

The method  `void backtracking(string s, int start)` is `O(2^(n - 1))` as every character you can either select or not select. So each character has 2 options. And hence `n` characters can present `2^n` options ideally `(2^(n-1))` as there has to be one character ideally.

Overall complexity is `O(2^n)`.

Comment: I don't think the complexity for ```void backtracking(...)``` is O(2^(n-1)). That is the number of subsets we could have with all characters within the string, which is not what we are after. What we are trying to do here is different ways of partitioning the string.

Comment: @DevDev Nope, it is the same. First you are adding it, and then you call backtracking, and then again you pop it out.